# How to load routes on initialization (Framework7+Vue)

Tags: vuejs2, html-framework-7

I am trying to build an app with framework7 and vue. All is well, except that when I start the app, it does not load the component specified on routes.js. I want it to load the component specified by the root url. How can I do this?

main.js

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  // Init Framework7 by passing parameters here
  framework7: {
    root: '#app',
    /* Uncomment to enable Material theme: */
     material: true,
     swipePanel: 'left',
     routes: Routes,
     pushState: true,
     animateNavBackIcon: true,
     input: {

     }
   },
 })
```

routes.js

```
export default [
    {
    path: '/',
    component: require('./assets/vue/pages/home.vue')
    }
]
```

Comment: I'm also stuck on this concept.  We have a main.vue that contains `f7-views -> f7-view -> f7-pages -> f7-page` where the last node contains our hardcoded 'home' screen. Now I'm abstracting that home screen out into home.vue and declaring it as '/' in the routes.  I can programatically call App.$f7.mainView.router.load({url: '/'}) once in the app, but doing this on startup e.g. in `mounted()` for the App, doesn't show my view.  Setting breakpoints shows the app actually tries to route to '/' on startup automatically but I just get a blank page.  Did you figure it out?

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm stuck on this also.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use the preroute object on framework7 Initialization, so that even before '/' route is loaded, I can manipulate the request and redirect to a particular route. Read more on preroute here: https://framework7.io/docs/init-app.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94027/285661) for instructions how to write *better* "link-based" answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is the same case as yours:

At first time, I did not add f7-view in my `application.html`, and the route did not work.

After adding `<f7-view main>`, the route started work and show the page.

I think `f7-view` is almost like `router-view`, is a output interface of the routing result.

If you add `f7-view` already, then just ignore this answer :-)